Merge into iceberg table from glue spark sql in cross region glue catalog
I have database and iceberg tables in us-east-1. I have to create glue job in us-west-2 and use spark sql to run a MERGE INTO SQL query to merge the incremental data into the iceberg table. The aws account is same.
What are the options to do this? Are there any iceberg configurations to specify the region as us-east-1?
I tried sharing the database and tables to the us-west-2 region via Lakeformation and grant super permissions. Then create the resource link in us-west-2 and try to do the merge. But it results in the error - Error Category: S3_ERROR; An error occurred while calling o109.sql. The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. (Service: S3, Status Code: 301, Request ID: 9GKJ20QBAEW0YMQ9, Extended Request ID: BZtiG5txe+Sjj4nfvC75iHKsc1m/+iZHwxt81vqcxHTrbQWpRWAfUMuuWil7HqQweVEYcl3PuMk=).
I should be able to access the S3 as the proper configurations are present in the glue connection. I am able to access that bucket normally in glue cross region when doing a create_dynamic_frame.

Did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same issue
